# setfacl(bash)isnt working

Tags: bash, shell

Well,i wanted to give a spesific user(lets call him Tom) some spesific rights to a folder  that i own.So i created a folder to my home directory called test1
-Then i setted the rights i wanted to give to him.Well it didnt work.These are the commands i used.

```
cd ~
mkdir test1
chmod 700 test1
setfacl -m u:Tom:rwx test1
```

The output of the getfacl command after that was

```
getfacl test1

# file: test1
# owner: Alator
# group: users
user::rwx
user:Tom:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
```

After all that Tom still couldnt access folder test1.any thoughts?

Comment: Can Tom access your home directory?

Comment: yes he can.He can ls in my home dir etc.

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com